# Shapeburst fill combined with graduated fill

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to fill some European countries with a color graduated relative to a certain quantity, and this color to fade off to black.

If I chose graduated, and then shape burst fill, I achieve the opposite: they are filled with a certain color (white in this case), which fades off to the graduated one at the country borders

[image]

Basically I'd like to achieve the opposite of the image above: countries in different shades of grey, shading to black at the borders.

Do you have anything in mind?

Comment: Did you try to invert/edit the color ramp of your graduated symbology ?